# User Control editing that I did not create

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am editing .ascx and .ascx.cs controls, however, I am seeing `using MMG.Global` and `using MMG.CMS` and these are namespaces within the .ascx control as follows:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MMG.Global" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MMG.CMS" %>
```

Well, the problem is that these files contain all of the objects that I will need as well, like buttons and placeholders, etc..  The new service will be with IDSS, and will replace MMG's service, but wondering if it is possible to edit these files and what would be involved in changing out the MMG to use IDSS instead?

I believe MMG is a reference that was used within the original project and when it was built was deployed within the .ascx and .ascx.cs files themselves.  But I don't know how this sort of thing works, which is why I'm asking.

What would be the best way to replace the 20 - 30 User Controls that have MMG prefixes?

In the MasterMain.master file, I have the following:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterMain.master.cs" Inherits="MasterMain"       %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="SEOControl"               Src="~/controls/SEOControl.ascx"            %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="ScriptControl"            Src="~/controls/ScriptControl.ascx"         %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="HeaderControl"            Src="~/controls/HeaderControl.ascx"         %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="HeroControl"              Src="~/controls/HeroControl.ascx"           %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="MenuFooterControl"        Src="~/controls/MenuFooterControl.ascx"     %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="StickyFooterControl"      Src="~/controls/StickyFooterControl.ascx"   %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="FavoritePromptControl"    Src="~/controls/Forms/FavoritePromptControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="LoginRegistrationControl" Src="~/controls/Forms/LoginRegistrationControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" TagName="EmailFavoriteFormControl" Src="~/controls/Forms/EmailFavoriteFormControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title runat="server" visible="false"></title>
        <mmg:SEOControl    ID="TheSEOControl"    runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal       ID="TheFavIcon"       runat="server" />
        <mmg:ScriptControl ID="TheScriptControl" runat="server" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TheHeadContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body class="" data-page="">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="TheScriptManager" runat="server">
                <CompositeScript>
                    <Scripts>
                        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"                            />
                        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"                    />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery.stickyfooter.js"             />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/modernizr.js"                       />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery-select2/select2.min.js"      />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"           />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"                />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/bootstrap-tab.js"                   />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"      />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/jquery.isotope.min.js"              />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/BaseUI.js"                          />                        
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/FavoriteUI.js"                      />
                        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/scripts/UserLoginUI.js"                     />


                    </Scripts>
                </CompositeScript>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <div id="Container" class="">
                <mmg:HeaderControl          ID="TheHeaderControl"       runat="server" />
                <mmg:HeroControl            ID="TheHeroControl"         runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder     ID="TheContentPlaceHolder"  runat="server" />
                <mmg:StickyFooterControl    ID="TheStickyFooterControl" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <mmg:MenuFooterControl      ID="TheMenuFooterControl"   runat="server" />
        </form>
        <mmg:FavoritePromptControl    ID="TheFavoritePromptControl"     runat="server" />
        <mmg:LoginRegistrationControl ID="TheLoginRegistrationControl"  runat="server" />
        <mmg:EmailFavoriteFormControl ID="TheEmailFavoriteFormControl"  runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript"> 
        UserLoginUI.SiteUser        = <%= _SiteUserJson %> 
        FavoriteUI.FavoriteList     = <%= _FavoritesJson %>
    </script>
```

But these aren't the namespaces, and wondering if I just edit the .ascx and .ascx.cs files, is that good enough?  Or would it be better to create a New Project and tie it in the same way that MMG is tied into it?

IDSS is a web service that needs to replace MMG, been struggling on how to implement this exactly within the current setup of the site.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, the problem is that these files contain all of the objects that
>   I will need as well, like buttons and placeholders, etc.. The new
>   service will be with IDSS, and will replace MMG's service, but
>   wondering if it is possible to edit these files and what would be
>   involved in changing out the MMG to use IDSS instead?

You can replace **mmg** with **idss** within **MasterMain.master** `<%@ Register TagPrefix="mmg" ... %>` to `<%@ Register TagPrefix="idss" ... %>`

If you do so, you will have to rename **all mmg tags** inside **MasterMain.master** like `<idss:SEOControl ID="TheSEOControl" runat="server" />`

> But these aren't the namespaces, and wondering if I just edit the
>   .ascx and .ascx.cs files, is that good enough?

You are correct. There are not namespace, so renaming tag does not do any harm.

**Note: if a control is registered inside web.config, you cannot simply rename in a single file. *However, it is not what I see in your scenario.* For example,**

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <controls>
     <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
        assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but where would I call upon the Web Service .asmx that is online within the IDSS?  Which file do you think would need to call it, and if I import the .ascx and .ascx.cs files (should I add in all .ascx and .ascx.cs files?) and edit these in a new Visual Studio Project, and add a reference to the IDSS .asmx file, can I than just save these files and overwrite on the server?  How would the Web Reference be added?  What to do to be sure it is added to the site?

Comment: Also, yes, you are correct, there are absolutely no controls registered in the `web.config` file.

Comment: There are namespaces defined within the .ascx.cs files (e.g. `using MMG.CMS` and `using MMG.Global`) and the .ascx file uses `Import` to get namespaces as well.  How do I find where these namespaces are defined and remove them?  Or do I just change the namespace?  And if so, to what?  Does it matter what the namespaces are named?  I'm sure it does...  Sorry for all of the questions... thanks so much for your help...

Comment: **WebService asmx** is nothing to do with User **Controls ascx**. If you want to add **Service Reference** to your project, look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/). Back to your original question, if your entire application's name space is **MMG.xxx**, you will end up updating all files. It is pain in the neck, unless you have a valid reason to do so.

Comment: Well, I need to replace MMG's service with IDSS, the names are not important, but the service is!  This is not my application.  It was created by someone else and tied into the site, so I don't believe it is the entire site.  It's just a lot of files throughout the site, is all.  Basically, I need to replace MMG's usercontrols with a Web Service instead.  How to do this quickly, but keep the same look and feel for the site?

Comment: I need to add Service Reference to the web site, not sure about the project.  I just want to edit MMG's already existing project to delete their service and replace with IDSS Service Reference instead.  Do I have to create a new project in order to do this?

Comment: Yes, if you want to replace **Service Reference**, you need to delete existing one and create a new one.

Comment: I need to replace MMG ***User Controls*** (.ascx files) with a ***Service Reference*** from IDSS.  Ok, so I will need to create a new project, but how do I remove all of the User Controls associated with MMG?  Just delete the lines in `MasterMain.master` file?  And remove all of the files .ascx and .ascx.cs in the ~/controls folder?  Is it not possible to include a Web Service Reference from a User Control?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see this:  `{SITE ROOT}/App_Code/MMG/Global` and `{SITE ROOT}/App_Code/MMG/CMS` folders.  These folders have a ton of `.cs` files in them.  This is where the `MMG.CMS` and `MMG.Global` namespaces are coming from!!!  Though I'm still a bit clueless